# Facing issue while executing the groovy code in JMeter

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, groovyshell

```
def hawkClient = new com.wealdtech.hawk.HawkClient.Builder()
                                          .credentials(new com.wealdtech.hawk.HawkCredentials.Builder()
                                              .keyId("UB6Vs7U8r45M9")
                                              .key("eFzPNjBgCFAbCFbu5NTxmSkGPYxqXLK3")
                                              .algorithm(Algorithm.sha256)
                                              .build())
                                           .build();
def authorization = hawkClient.generateAuthorizationHeader(sampler.getUrl().toURI(), sampler.getMethod(), sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue())
vars.put('authorization', authorization)
```

when I execute this above snippet in JMeter got this error " javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: Algorithm for class: Script47"

can someone please help me to fix it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an appropriate `import` statement to the beginning of your script:

```
import com.wealdtech.hawk.HawkCredentials
```

or just use fully qualified class name:

```
.algorithm(com.wealdtech.hawk.HawkCredentials.Algorithm.SHA256)
```

More information:

- [HawkCredentials.Algorithm](http://wealdtech.github.io/hawk/docs/hawk-core/com/wealdtech/hawk/HawkCredentials.Algorithm.html)
- [Groovy Program Structure - Imports](https://groovy-lang.org/structure.html#_imports)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Hi @Dmitri thanks for your answer. But when I updated the above snippet and executed , it gives another error like .."java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getValue() on null object
"     can you please guide me why this error is coming ? #Jmeter #jmeter #groovy

Comment: Maybe your request body is empty, in this case you can try replacing `sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue()` with an empty string. It's quite hard to guess what you're trying to achieve, what is hawk protocol version your app is using, etc.

Comment: Hi @Dmitri , I want to pass a GET API call through JMeter which requires Hawk Authentication and there is no request body . In postman It works fine but in JMeter It gets failed .